# List of trusted CA in android?

Tags: android, ssl, https

i would like to know which Certification Authorities are "allowed" on android..

Since i'm going to buy a ssl certificate i would like to understand if i'll get some problems in android using it.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This list http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2010/09/23/android-root-certification-authorities-list/ helps me solve the problem described here: [Apache HttpClient on Android producing CertPathValidatorException (IssuerName != SubjectName)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115101/apache-httpclient-on-android-producing-certpathvalidatorexception-issuername)

Comment: Lol :) That's my website ;)

Comment: Can you include the relevant info here? Otherwise it is a link only answer, which could disappear any time.

Answer (score 2):

You can download certs from android device or emulator http://www.setupmobile.se/?p=78 and then check whether it contains needed root ca