# javax.net.ssl.sslpeerunverifiedexception no peer certificate

Tags: android, ssl, https

I am trying to insert a record into MySQL by posting data to a PHP server from an Android app. I have added the INTERNET permission to AndroidManifest.xml

I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate`

Android code

```
private void senddata(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data)
{
    try 
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://10.0.2.2/insert222.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you solved your issue or still its pending?

Answer (score 7):

> **Warning**: Do not implement this in production code you are ever going to use on a network you do not entirely trust. Especially anything going over the public internet. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9582529/1979882) gives more correct answer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378872/1979882) is an implementation using SSL.

Your problem is you are using DefaultHttpClient for `https`(secure url). 
Create a custom DefaultHttpClient

```
public static HttpClient createHttpClient()
{
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

    SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
    schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
    ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schReg);

    return new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);
}
```

Than change your code as follows:

```
        HttpClient httpclient = createHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://10.0.2.2/insert222.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837230/1503155) if you have problems
It should work.

Comment: You shouldn't advise people to 'trust all the certificates' without also advising them of the security breach that is involved.

Comment: @EJP you are right! The link I direct him to has the WARNING! Maybe thats not enough.

Comment: The warning should be here.

Comment: `The method getSocketFactory() is undefined for the type SSLSocketFactory`. Why? EDIT: just use `import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;` instead of `import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;`

Comment: I have used the above method. i still i am getting an error javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLNullSession.getPeerCertificates(SSLNullSession.java:104)  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93) at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with an IIS 8 server. In the https binding, I had to uncheck the checkbox labeled "Require Server Name Indication." Once I unchecked it, I quit getting the error.

Comment: @skrrgwasme when reviewing these, be sure to read the entire sentence. While it starts off sounding like it's going to be a question or an 'I'm having this problem too' comment, this is not.

Comment: @McAdam331 You're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing it out. I do try to read the whole post, but obviously made a mistake on this one.

Comment: @skrrgwasme happens to the best of us, just wanted to make sure you knew.

Comment: @Tim Cooke, please ignore the comment I made earlier. As McAdam331 helpfully pointed out, it was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say all trusted certificates (trusted by authorized centres such as COMODO, Symantec, etc.) have to be work in any case. If your app recieves such **javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate** using bought certificate you give something wrong on server side.
 To test use `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443` command to get inner information about certificate your app recieve.
In may case my nginx-server sent wrong certificate in some cases.