# Spring RestTemplate I/O error: No peer certificate

Tags: android, spring, ssl, resttemplate, self-signed

I always get the same error whens try to get a https resource:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: No peer certificate; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

I have a self-signed virtual host where my app runs, the app works fine on `http` but I need `https`.

Here is my code in android app:

```
mRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();
mRestTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
mRestTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());

final ResponseObject responseObject = mRestTemplate.postForObject(APP_URL, requestObject, ResponseObject.class);
```

---

### Update 1

- I tried the solution proposed by @nilesh and has not worked.
- I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17159839/816721) with the same error

  ```
  HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
  HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
  HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
  HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

  SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
  schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
  schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
  ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schReg);

  client = DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);

  final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
      factory.setHttpClient(client);

  mRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  mRestTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
  ```
- I tried [this solution](http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/) without success and the same error

  1. Grab all required certificates (root and any intermediate CA’s)
  2. Create a keystore with keytool and the BouncyCastle provider and import the certs
  3. Load the keystore in your android app and use it for the secured connections
     Don’t use the standard java.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection for the secure connection. Use the Apache HttpClient (Version 4 atm) library, which is already built-in in android. It’s built on top of the java connection libraries and is, in my opinion, faster, better modularized and easier to understand.

Answer (score 8):

Run the method below before making any Http request using RestTemplate. This works for me.

```
public void trustSelfSignedSSL() {
        try {
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs,
                        String string) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs,
                        String string) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

                }
            };
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
            SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred ",ex)
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have a problem `SSLContext.setDefault` is only available for api 9+ i need a solution for api 8 and this dont works.

Comment: What is api 9+? Above code works for me with jdk 1.6. Import is-> import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext

Comment: please see the android doc http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#setDefault(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext)

Comment: I do see SSLContext.setDefault in the link you mention. Did you mean to send a different link?

Comment: @nilesh - How did you set the trustSelfSignedSSL() method to rest template ?

Comment: @PAA it was long back, but I believe I called trustSelfSignedSSL() before the test started