# How to disable SSL certificate checking with Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, self-signed

I am trying to write an integration test where our test launches an embedded HTTPS server using [Simple](http://www.simpleframework.org/). I [created a self-signed certificate using `keytool`](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html) and am able to access the server using a browser (specifically Chrome, and I do get a warning about the self-signed certificate).

However, when I try to connect using [Spring RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), I get a [ResourceAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResourceAccessException.html):

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8088":sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:557)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:502)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:444)
    at net.initech.DummySslServer.shouldConnect(DummySslServer.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:156)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:925)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:860)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:541)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1351)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 53 more
```

From [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072585/disabling-ssl-certificate-validation-in-spring-resttemplate) and [blog](http://www.jroller.com/jurberg/entry/using_a_hostnameverifier_with_spring) [posts](http://www.jroller.com/hasant/entry/no_subject_alternative_names_matching) I've seen the advice to replace the `HostnameVerifier` with something like

```
private static final HostnameVerifier PROMISCUOUS_VERIFIER = ( s, sslSession ) -> true;
```

And I've set it both globally and on the `RestTemplate` itself:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier( PROMISCUOUS_VERIFIER );
```

...and on the `RestTemplate` itself:

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setRequestFactory( new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    @Override
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException {
        if(connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection ){
            ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setHostnameVerifier(PROMISCUOUS_VERIFIER);
        }
        super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
    }
});
```

Yet, I am still getting the above error. How can I get around it?

1. Installing the certificate locally *outside* of the unit test is *not* an option as then it would need to get installed manually on every dev machine and build server and would cause an avalanche of red tape.
2. We need SSL since we are testing a library that sits on top of `RestTemplate` and that we are configuring it correctly.

I am using Java 8 (but could use 7) and Spring 4.0.3 .

Comment: You'll need to manually configure the HTTP connector the template is using.

Comment: @chrylis I don't see a class of the name `HttpConnector` in either Java's SDK or Springs JavaDoc. Which class did you mean specifically?

Comment: Did you check my answer over [here][1]. This works for me.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476073/spring-resttemplate-i-o-error-no-peer-certificate/18583448#18583448

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection

Comment: Sled, Could you please confirm how did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I wish I still had a link to the source that lead me in this direction, but this is the code that ended up working for me. By looking over the JavaDoc for [X509TrustManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html) it looks like the way the `TrustManager`s work is by returning nothing on successful validation, otherwise throwing an exception. Thus, with a [null implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), it is treated as a successful validation. Then you remove all other implementations.

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public final class SSLUtil{

    private static final TrustManager[] UNQUESTIONING_TRUST_MANAGER = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted( X509Certificate[] certs, String authType ){}
                public void checkServerTrusted( X509Certificate[] certs, String authType ){}
            }
        };

    public  static void turnOffSslChecking() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init( null, UNQUESTIONING_TRUST_MANAGER, null );
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    }

    public static void turnOnSslChecking() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        // Return it to the initial state (discovered by reflection, now hardcoded)
        SSLContext.getInstance("SSL").init( null, null, null );
    }

    private SSLUtil(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Do not instantiate libraries.");
    }
}
```

Comment: @ArtB whats the collect usage for the code? should I call SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking() each time before calling the rest URL? any code example please

Comment: It depends on your use case. But I recommend having the turn off in the `@Before` method in a unit test and the turn back on in the `@After`.

Comment: In my tests this definitely turned off SSL checks but the turnOn() method failed to restore SSL checking, I posted an incremental improvement in an answer below.

Comment: How can we use this with RestTemplate ?

Comment: @PAA You can make a call to SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking() just before your RestTemplate initialization.

Answer (score 61):

For the sake of other developers who finds this question and need another solution that fits not only for unit-tests:

I've found [this](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2016/02/skip-ssl-certificate-verification-in.html) on a blog (not my solution! Credit to the blog's owner).

```
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
        .build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
        .build();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my situation, I still get: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: Please note this answer assumes you have configured your Spring environment, maybe Spring-Boot, to use Apache HTTP Client as the implementation, which is NOT the default.

Comment: After this implementation, I am getting SSLPeerUnverifiedException. how to resolve that

Comment: I was using the apache provided `new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()` in loadTrustMaterial but still getting the error. Then i replaced it with `TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;` as recommended above, and it works fine now!

Comment: it worked for me. I needed to call an external internet hosted HTTPS Endpoint from my Tomcat 8.5 running SpringBoot WAR. 

Earlier, when i was running my app through "mvn spring-boot:run", HTTPS endpoint  was getting called successfully but running the WAR inside Tomcat 8.5 Container was failing to call the HTTPS Endpoint.


needed to add below dependency:
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.1</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 15):

Please see below for a modest improvement on @Sled's code shown above, that turn-back-on method was missing one line, now it passes my tests.  This disables HTTPS certificate and hostname spoofing when using RestTemplate in a Spring-Boot version 2 application that uses the **default HTTP configuration**, NOT configured to use Apache HTTP Client.

```
package org.my.little.spring-boot-v2.app;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

/**
 * Disables and enables certificate and host-name checking in
 * HttpsURLConnection, the default JVM implementation of the HTTPS/TLS protocol.
 * Has no effect on implementations such as Apache Http Client, Ok Http.
*/
public final class SSLUtils {

    private static final HostnameVerifier jvmHostnameVerifier = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();

    private static final HostnameVerifier trivialHostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession sslSession) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    private static final TrustManager[] UNQUESTIONING_TRUST_MANAGER = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    } };

    public static void turnOffSslChecking() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(trivialHostnameVerifier);
        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, UNQUESTIONING_TRUST_MANAGER, null);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    }

    public static void turnOnSslChecking() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(jvmHostnameVerifier);
        // Return it to the initial state (discovered by reflection, now hardcoded)
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, null, null);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    }

    private SSLUtils() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Do not instantiate libraries.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This updated solution worked for me.  FYI For more inform on the implementation of hostname verification in `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient`, there's a [huge comment block](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/https/HttpsClient.java#L478) detailing the algorithm that is used which can be explicitly set.  I originally thought that just simply setting the default `HostnameVerifier` would be sufficient but its not and I think its because of the default hostname verification algorithm being used.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I called it before startup of the Spring Boot app in the main method.

Comment: Finally! A solution that actually works that does not rely on not-present Apache http or other non-standard configurations!

Comment: In case it isn't obvious to others, you have to call `SSLUtils.turnOffSslChecking()` prior to constructing your `RestTemplate` (or maybe just prior to usage)

Answer (score 10):

```
@Bean(name = "restTemplateByPassSSL")
public RestTemplate restTemplateByPassSSL()
        throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = (s, sslSession) -> true;
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain how this answers OP's question.

Comment: Looking closer, it looks like this code snippet is identical to @OhadR's answer. How is this any different?

Comment: it worked for me. I needed to call an external internet hosted HTTPS Endpoint from my Tomcat 8.5 running SpringBoot WAR. 

Earlier, when i was running my app through "mvn spring-boot:run", HTTPS endpoint  was getting called successfully but running the WAR inside Tomcat 8.5 Container was failing to call the HTTPS Endpoint.

needed to add below dependency:
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.1</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 7):

You can also register your keystore :

```
private void registerKeyStore(String keyStoreName) {
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream keyStoreInputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(keyStoreName);
        if (keyStoreInputStream == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find file named '" + keyStoreName + "' in the CLASSPATH");
        }

        //load the keystore
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(keyStoreInputStream, null);

        //add to known keystore 
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(keystore);

        //default SSL connections are initialized with the keystore above
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustManagers, null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(sc);
    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution where security checking is disabled (for example, conversing with the localhost)  Also, some of the solutions I've seen now contain deprecated methods and such.

```
/**
 * @param configFilePath
 * @param ipAddress
 * @param userId
 * @param password
 * @throws MalformedURLException
 */
public Upgrade(String aConfigFilePath, String ipAddress, String userId, String password) {
    configFilePath = aConfigFilePath;
    baseUri = "https://" + ipAddress + ":" + PORT + "/";

    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(createSecureTransport(userId, password, ipAddress, PORT));
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
 }

ClientHttpRequestFactory createSecureTransport(String username,
        String password, String host, int port) {
    HostnameVerifier nullHostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), credentials);

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(nullHostnameVerifier)
            .setSSLContext(createContext())
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = 
            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);

    return requestFactory;
}

private SSLContext createContext() {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    } };

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(sc);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        return sc;

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Too late but here you have my solution. With this class you can turn off all ssl verifications in your project.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;


@Slf4j
@Component
public class SslWarningRemover {

    public SslWarningRemover() {
        log.info("Disabling SSL warning...");
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return null;
                        }
                        
                        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                            
                        }
                        
                        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                            
                        }
                    }
            };
            
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            
            log.info("SSL verification disabled");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while trying to disable SSL verification: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        
        log.info("SSL warning process remover has finished!");
    }
}
```

If you want to disable the SSL verification in a single RestTemplate, try this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;


@Slf4j
public class CustomClientHttpRequestFactory extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {
    
    private static final HostnameVerifier PROMISCUOUS_VERIFIER = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    
    private static final TrustManager[] ALL_CERT_TRUST_MANAGER = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    
                }
                
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    
                }
            }
    };
    
    private static SSLContext ALL_CERT_TRUST_SSLCONTEXT = null;
    
    static {
        try {
            ALL_CERT_TRUST_SSLCONTEXT = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            ALL_CERT_TRUST_SSLCONTEXT.init(null, ALL_CERT_TRUST_MANAGER, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error disabling SSL verification");
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    
    
    private boolean disableSslVerification = false;
    
    public CustomClientHttpRequestFactory(int connectTimeout, int readTimeout, boolean disableSslVerification) {
        this.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        this.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        this.disableSslVerification = disableSslVerification;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException {
        if (disableSslVerification && ALL_CERT_TRUST_SSLCONTEXT != null && connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
            ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setHostnameVerifier(PROMISCUOUS_VERIFIER);
            ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setSSLSocketFactory(ALL_CERT_TRUST_SSLCONTEXT.getSocketFactory());
        }
        super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
    }
    
}
```

Then, when you instance a RestTemplate object, use this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new CustomClientHttpRequestFactory(connectTimeout, readTimeout, disableSslVerification));
```

with **disableSslVerification** parameter as *true*.

Comment: This is working from my side in 2022 with spring boot 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

Iknow It is too old to answer, but I couldn't find solution like this.

The code that worked for me with the jersey client:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

public class Testi {

static {
    disableSslVerification();
}
private static void disableSslVerification() {
    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    // Install the all-trusting host verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
}

public Testi() {
    MultivaluedHashMap<String, Object> headers = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
    //... initialize headers

    Form form = new Form();
    Entity<Form> entity = Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE);
    // initialize entity ...

    WebTarget target = getWebTarget();
    Object responseResult = target.path("api/test/path...").request()
            .headers(headers).post(entity, Object.class);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Testi();
}

private WebTarget getWebTarget() {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 30000);
    clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 30000);

    SSLContext sc = getSSLContext();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sc).withConfig(clientConfig).build();
    WebTarget target = client.target("...url...");
    return target;
}

private SSLContext getSSLContext() {
    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

            }

            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        return sc;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share, at least for myself, my code based on other answers.

```java
// Spring Boot 2.7.5 / Java 11
@PostConstruct
private void onPostConstruct() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
    // http://www.chrispad.com/2019/02/disable-certificate-verification-using.html
    var sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial((c, at) -> true).build();
    var socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, (h, s) -> true);
    var httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
    var requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    template = templateBuilder.requestFactory(() -> requestFactory).build();
}

private final RestTemplateBuilder templateBuilder;

private RestTemplate template;:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            private static void disableSslVerification() {
            try
            {
                // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
                TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
                };

                // Install the all-trusting trust manager
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

                // Create all-trusting host name verifier
                HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                };

                // Install the all-trusting host verifier
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Apache HttpClient 5, `SSLSocketFactory` should be set on the `ConnectionManager`. This is the updated version of @Debasis-Mishra's answer:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("trust-all-certs")
public RestTemplate getTrustingRestTemplate() {
    try {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = (s, sslSession) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);
        HttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, with letsencrypt https, this was caused by using `cert.pem` instead of `fullchain.pem` as the certificate file on the requested server. See [this thread](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certificate-error-sun-security-validator-validatorexception-pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/28283) for details.

Answer (score -32):

Disabling certificate checking is the wrong solution, and radically insecure.

The correct solution is to import the self-signed certificate into your truststore. An even more correct solution is to get the certificate signed by a CA.

If this is 'only for testing' it is still necessary to test the production configuration. Testing something else isn't a test at all, it's just a waste of time.

Comment: This is only within a unit test. Within the unit test I am bringing up a dummy version of our client' server to which we will be sending commands. In production the client server has a CA signed certificate. However, they do not have a test environment. Many of our commands are destructive so I am using our dummy client server to record the messages we are sending it so we can check them for compliance. The libraries we are using force SSL so to capture the full content of the messages we are sending them.

Comment: Not answering the question. Sometimes it is necessary for debug purposes to disable SSL check.

Comment: @Alex Debugging purposes such as what? How is providing 'the correct solution' not answering the question?

Comment: @EJP the question is clearly asking "How to disable SSL certificate checking with Spring RestTemplate?". The answer you have provided doesn't answer that question. As I was also looking for the answer to that question I didn't find it in your comment.

Comment: There are a number of reasons the certificate may be self-signed.  Not all organizations provide signed certificates in all environments, for example.  Your comment doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It is useful to be able to disable certificate checking in specific cases. The reason for doing so should be reviewed on a case by case basis, but the ability to do isn't provided in your answer

Comment: @GerardDownes It is useful in *what* cases? Where are these mysterious cases where you don't care who issued the certificate? Have you read RFC 2616 on the topic?

Comment: @ipaul Using a self-signed certificate does not mandate disabling all certificate checking. If anything it makes it all the more important.

Comment: I'm developing an intranet service where it is crucial to send requests within a private network. The resource to consume is behind https(not with trusted CA, because obviously it's intranet), and inaccessible through http. In the future, please avoid posting overly personal opinions to a question while not even answering it. Comment sections exist for a that purpose.

Comment: @GyuhyeonLee Rubbish. There is nothing 'personal' about this 'opinion', All it does it reiterate the design intent behind X.509, which happened 3 decades ago, without my participation, and all of which is still in effect.