# How do I convert a curl request with HTTP basic authentication to a Spring RestTemplate request?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

How do I convert the following `curl` request to use Spring's RestTemplate?

```
curl -u 751061:123456 -i -k -X PUT https://server/api/User/751061 -H 'Content-type: application/xml' -d '<User><state>LOGIN</state><extension>751055</extension></User>'
```

I tried following the guide but it doesn't mention anything at all about authentication (nor XML).

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/#_make_the_application_executable

The API doc doesn't mention anything at all about authentication.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

I tried the following

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestParam(name="userId", required=true) String userId,
        @RequestParam(name="password", required=true) String password,
        @RequestParam(name="extension", required=true) String extension,
        HttpSession session,
        RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    User user = new User();
    user.state = "LOGIN";
    user.extension = extension;
//      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
//      restTemplate.set
    RestTemplate restTemplate = builder.basicAuthorization(userId, password).build();
    restTemplate.put("https://server/api/User/"+userId, user);
```

But got the exception

```
2018-09-14 22:19:44.038 ERROR 143068 --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Customizers must not be null] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Customizers must not be null
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.<init>(RestTemplateBuilder.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
```

---

I tried the following

```
public String login(@RequestParam(name="userId", required=true) String userId,
        @RequestParam(name="password", required=true) String password,
        @RequestParam(name="extension", required=true) String extension,
        HttpSession session
        /*RestTemplateBuilder builder*/) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    User user = new User();
    user.state = "LOGIN";
    user.extension = extension;

    // turn off SSL checking // https://stackoverflow.com/a/24491820/148844
    X509TrustManager[] tm = new X509TrustManager[] {new TrustAllX509TrustManager()}; // from IdS client SDK
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init( null, tm, null );
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    // set authentication headers
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    String plainClientCredentials = userId + ":" + password;
    String base64ClientCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainClientCredentials.getBytes()));
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64ClientCredentials);
    HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(null, headers);
    // make request
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = "https://server/api/User/"+userId;
    restTemplate.put(url, request, user);
```

But got the error

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:766) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:724) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.put(RestTemplate.java:495) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
```

It works with `curl`.

---

I added

```
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ResponseErrorHandler() {

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse arg0) throws IOException {
        byte[] b = new byte[arg0.getBody().available()];
        arg0.getBody().read(b);
        System.out.println(new String(b));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse arg0) throws IOException {
        return arg0.getRawStatusCode() != 202;
    }

});
System.out.println("\n\n\n********************************************************************");
restTemplate.put(url, request, user);
```

And got

```
********************************************************************
<ApiErrors>
  <ApiError>
    <ErrorType>Invalid Input</ErrorType>
    <ErrorData>User</ErrorData>
    <ErrorMessage> : Premature end of file.</ErrorMessage>
  </ApiError>
</ApiErrors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("username", "password"));
```

Comment: I still get `<ErrorMessage> : Premature end of file.</ErrorMessage>`. `400 Bad Request`.

Comment: The problem is in your Pojo (User) or in how you are passing it to the put method. You have to use `restTemplate.put(url, user)`

Comment: I still have to include the `request` variable to set the `Content-type` header to `APPLICATION_XML`.

Comment: Ok, but you are using the api wrongly.  
Try this:

`HttpEntity<User> request = new HttpEntity<User>(user, headers);
restTemplate.put(url, request);`