# Ignoring self-signed certificates in SpringBoot using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, certificate, resttemplate, self-signed-certificate

I'm working on a SpringBoot application which needs to make RESTful calls to an internal API that uses a self-signed certificate.

I'm only having this issue in DEV and QA since in UAT and PROD they're using a properly signed certificate.

I'm developing on a Windows 10 machine and using Java 8.

---

**I've tried the below with no luck:**

### Added certificate to Windows trusted certificates

1. I downloaded the certificate from Chrome (in the address bar where
   it shows that the certificate is not valid).
2. Then, in Windows Explorer, I right-clicked the certificate file and selected **Install Certificate** and followed the wizard.

### Adding code to ignore SSL verification

I called the **SSLUtils.buildRestTemplate** method when creating a **RestTemplate**.

```
package com.company.project.utils.ssl;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.company.project.beans.ssl.SslBypassConfiguration;

/**
 * This class contains several methods for manipulating SSL certificate verification.
 */
public class SSLUtils
{

    /* PRIVATE CONSTANTS */
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SSLUtils.class);

    /* PRIVATE VARIABLES */
    private static HostnameVerifier defaultHostnameVerifier = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();

    /* PUBLIC METHODS */
    /**
     * This method will set custom SSL certificate verification which will
     * only forgo SSL certificate verification for white-listed hostnames.
     * 
     * @param sslBypassConfiguration
     * The {@link SslBypassConfiguration} that contains the details needed.
     * 
     * @return
     * The boolean flag to denote if the operation was successful.
     * 
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * If no Provider supports aSSLContextSpi implementation for the
     * specified protocol.
     * @throws KeyManagementException
     * If the initialization fails.
     */
    public static boolean setCustomSslChecking(final SslBypassConfiguration sslBypassConfiguration)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        // If the SSL bypass is enabled, then keep going.
        if (sslBypassConfiguration.isSslVerificationBypassEnabled())
        {
            // If there are some hostnames to white-list, then keep going.
            if ((sslBypassConfiguration.getWhitelistedHostnames() != null) && (sslBypassConfiguration.getWhitelistedHostnames().size() > 0))
            {
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hostnames Being White-Listed:\n");

                // Loop over all white-listed hostnames and log them.
                for (Entry<String, String> whitelistedHostname : sslBypassConfiguration.getWhitelistedHostnames().entrySet())
                {
                    sb.append(whitelistedHostname.getKey())
                    .append(" (")
                    .append(whitelistedHostname.getValue())
                    .append(")");
                }

                logger.warn(sb.toString());
            }
            else
            {
                logger.warn("SSL certificate verification bypass is enabled, but no white-listed hostnames have been specified.");
            }

            // Create the hostname verifier to be used.
            final WhitelistHostnameVerifier whitelistHostnameVerifier = new WhitelistHostnameVerifier(sslBypassConfiguration);

            // Create the trust manager to be used.
            final X509TrustManager trustManager = new TrustingX509TrustManager();

            // Assign the custom hostname verifier and trust manager.
            SSLUtils.setCustomSslChecking(whitelistHostnameVerifier, trustManager);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This method will set custom SSL certificate verification.
     * 
     * @param hostnameVerifier
     * The {@link javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier} that will be used to verify hostnames.
     * @param trustManager
     * The {@link X509TrustManager} that will be used to verify certificates.
     * 
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * If no Provider supports aSSLContextSpi implementation for the specified protocol.
     * @throws KeyManagementException
     * If the initialization fails.
     */
    public static void setCustomSslChecking(
            final javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier,
            final X509TrustManager trustManager)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        // Get an instance of the SSLContent.
        final SSLContext sslContent = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); // TLS

        // Set the state using the specified TrustManager.
        sslContent.init(null, new TrustManager[] {trustManager}, null);

        // Set the derived SSL socket factory.
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContent.getSocketFactory());

        // Define the default hostname verifier.
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
    }

    /**
     * This method will set the default SSL certificate verification.
     * 
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * If no Provider supports aSSLContextSpi implementation for the specified protocol.
     * @throws KeyManagementException
     * If the initialization fails.
     */
    public static void setDefaultSslChecking()
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        // Get an instance of the SSLContent.
        final SSLContext sslContent = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); // TLS

        // Return it to the initial state (discovered by reflection, now hardcoded).
        sslContent.init(null, null, null);

        // Set the default SSL socket factory.
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContent.getSocketFactory());

        // Define the default hostname verifier.
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(SSLUtils.defaultHostnameVerifier);
    }

    /**
     * This method will build a new {@link RestTemplate}.
     * 
     * @param sslBypassConfiguration
     * The {@link SslBypassConfiguration}.
     * 
     * @return
     * The {@link RestTemplate}.
     * 
     * @throws KeyManagementException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws KeyStoreException
     */
    public static RestTemplate buildRestTemplate(final SslBypassConfiguration sslBypassConfiguration)
            throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException
    {
        if ((sslBypassConfiguration == null) || (!sslBypassConfiguration.isSslVerificationBypassEnabled()))
        {
            return new RestTemplate();
        }

        final TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = new TrustStrategy()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(final java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType)
                    throws java.security.cert.CertificateException
            {
                return true;
            }
        };

        final HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();


        final SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
        final SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

        httpClientBuilder.setSSLSocketFactory(csf);
        httpClientBuilder.setSSLHostnameVerifier(new WhitelistHostnameVerifier(sslBypassConfiguration));

        final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClientBuilder.build());

        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }

}
```

### Possible Idea

Is there an application that could accept HTTP connections and route them to an externally hosted HTTPS endpoint?

This application would have to ignore any certificate issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest configuration that turn off all ssl verification is:

with a factory

```
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
```

trust all TLS with the `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier` class from

```
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>`
```

Create a new client

```
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom() .loadTrustMaterial(null, (chain, authType) -> true) .build(); 
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[]{"TLSv1"}, null, new NoopHostnameVerifier()); 
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
```

Create a new resttemplate with this new client

```
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

resuming:

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom() .loadTrustMaterial(null, (chain, authType) -> true) .build(); 
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[]{"TLSv1"}, null, new NoopHostnameVerifier()); 
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
    
    
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

Answer (score 1):

RestTemplate跳过https请求证书验证问题：

@Override
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) {

```
    try {
        if (!(connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("An instance of HttpsURLConnection is expected");
        }

        HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) connection;

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }

                }
        };
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        httpsConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(new MyCustomSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()));

        httpsConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        super.prepareConnection(httpsConnection, httpMethod);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


// SSLSocketFactory用于创建 SSLSockets
private static class MyCustomSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

    public MyCustomSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    // 返回默认启用的密码套件。除非一个列表启用，对SSL连接的握手会使用这些密码套件。
    // 这些默认的服务的最低质量要求保密保护和服务器身份验证
    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    // 返回的密码套件可用于SSL连接启用的名字
    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }


    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final Socket socket, final String host, final int port, 
            final boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
         Socket underlyingSocket = null;
        try {
            underlyingSocket = delegate.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return overrideProtocol(underlyingSocket);
    }


    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final String host, final int port) throws IOException {
        Socket underlyingSocket = null;
        try {
            underlyingSocket = delegate.createSocket(host, port);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return overrideProtocol(underlyingSocket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final String host, final int port, final InetAddress localAddress, 
            final int localPort) throws
            IOException {
        Socket underlyingSocket = null;
        try {
            underlyingSocket = delegate.createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return overrideProtocol(underlyingSocket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final InetAddress host, final int port) throws IOException {
        Socket underlyingSocket = null;
        try {
            underlyingSocket = delegate.createSocket(host, port);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return overrideProtocol(underlyingSocket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final InetAddress host, final int port, final InetAddress localAddress, 
            final int localPort) throws
            IOException {
        Socket underlyingSocket = null;
        try {
            underlyingSocket = delegate.createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return overrideProtocol(underlyingSocket);
    }

    private Socket overrideProtocol(final Socket socket) {
        if (!(socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("An instance of SSLSocket is expected");
        }
        ((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1"});
        return socket;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to ignoring SSL verification for RestTemplates.
I can't take the credit though, I found the answer on another question: [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33619237/1827349)

Here's my code if anyone else can use it.

### SSLUtils

```
package com.company.project.utils.ssl;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.company.project.beans.ssl.SslBypassConfiguration;

/**
 * This class contains several methods for manipulating SSL certificate verification.
 * 
 * @author Matthew Weiler
 */
public class SSLUtils
{

    /* PRIVATE CONSTANTS */
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SSLUtils.class);

    /* PUBLIC CONSTANTS */
    public static final HostnameVerifier DEFAULT_HOSTNAMEVERIFIER = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();

    /* PUBLIC METHODS */
    /**
     * This method will build a {@link RestTemplate}.
     * 
     * @param sslBypassConfiguration
     * The {@link SslBypassConfiguration}.
     * @param username
     * The username to be used when establishing a connection.
     * @param password
     * The password to be used when establishing a connection.
     * 
     * @return
     * The {@link RestTemplate}.
     * 
     * @throws KeyManagementException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     */
    public static RestTemplate buildRestTemplate(final SslBypassConfiguration sslBypassConfiguration, final String username, final String password)
            throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(SSLUtils.createSecureTransport(sslBypassConfiguration, username, password));

        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        return restTemplate;
    }

    /* PROTECTED METHODS */
    /**
     * This method will build a {@link ClientHttpRequestFactory}.
     * 
     * @param sslBypassConfiguration
     * The {@link SslBypassConfiguration}.
     * @param username
     * The username to be used when establishing a connection.
     * @param password
     * The password to be used when establishing a connection.
     * 
     * @return
     * The {@link ClientHttpRequestFactory}.
     * 
     * @throws KeyManagementException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     */
    protected static ClientHttpRequestFactory createSecureTransport(final SslBypassConfiguration sslBypassConfiguration, final String username, final String password) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        final HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

        if (sslBypassConfiguration.isSslVerificationBypassEnabled())
        {
            httpClientBuilder.setSSLHostnameVerifier(new WhitelistHostnameVerifier(sslBypassConfiguration));
        }

        httpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(SSLUtils.createContext(sslBypassConfiguration));

        // If credentials are supplied, apply them to the http-client-builder.
        if (((username != null) && (username.trim().length() > 0)) || ((password != null) && (password.trim().length() > 0)))
        {
            final UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
            final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

            credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), credentials);

            httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
        }

        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClientBuilder.build());
    }

    /**
     * This method will build a {@link SSLContext}.
     * 
     * @param sslBypassConfiguration
     * The {@link SslBypassConfiguration}.
     * 
     * @return
     * The {@link SSLContext}.
     * 
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws KeyManagementException
     */
    protected static SSLContext createContext(final SslBypassConfiguration sslBypassConfiguration)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

        if (sslBypassConfiguration.isSslVerificationBypassEnabled())
        {
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager()
            {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                {

                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                {

                }
            }};

            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);
        }
        else
        {
            sslContext.init(null, null, null);
        }

        SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

        if (sslBypassConfiguration.isSslVerificationBypassEnabled())
        {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new WhitelistHostnameVerifier(sslBypassConfiguration));
        }
        else
        {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(SSLUtils.DEFAULT_HOSTNAMEVERIFIER);
        }

        return sslContext;
    }

}
```

### WhitelistHostnameVerifier

```
package com.company.project.utils.ssl;

import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import com.company.project.beans.ssl.SslBypassConfiguration;

/**
 * This {@link HostnameVerifier} will ignore the SSL validation for hostnames that are on the white-list.
 * 
 * @author Matthew Weiler
 */
public class WhitelistHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier
{

    /* PRIVATE CONSTANTS */
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(WhitelistHostnameVerifier.class);

    /* PRIVATE VARIABLES */
    private final SslBypassConfiguration sslBypassConfiguration;

    /* CONSTRUCTORS */
    /**
     * This will create a new {@link WhitelistHostnameVerifier}.
     * 
     * @param sslBypassConfiguration
     * The {@link SslBypassConfiguration} to be used.
     */
    public WhitelistHostnameVerifier(
            final SslBypassConfiguration sslBypassConfiguration)
    {
        this.sslBypassConfiguration = sslBypassConfiguration;
    }

    /* PUBLIC METHODS */
    @Override
    public boolean verify(final String host, final SSLSession session)
    {
        if (this.sslBypassConfiguration.isSslVerificationBypassEnabled())
        {
            if ((this.sslBypassConfiguration.getWhitelistedHostnames() != null) && (this.sslBypassConfiguration.getWhitelistedHostnames().size() > 0))
            {
                for (Entry<String, String> whitelistEntry : this.sslBypassConfiguration.getWhitelistedHostnames().entrySet())
                {
                    if (whitelistEntry.getValue().equals(host))
                    {
                        logger.info("Not performing validation on SSL connection for: " + whitelistEntry.getKey() + " (" + whitelistEntry.getValue() + ")");

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // important: use default verifier for all other hosts
        return SSLUtils.DEFAULT_HOSTNAMEVERIFIER.verify(host, session);
    }

    /**
     * This method will get the {@link SslBypassConfiguration}.
     * 
     * @return
     * The {@link SslBypassConfiguration}.
     */
    public SslBypassConfiguration getSslConfiguration()
    {
        return this.sslBypassConfiguration;
    }

}
```

### SslBypassConfiguration

```
package com.company.project.mobile.beans.ssl;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.company.project.utils.StringUtils;

/**
 * This {@link HostnameVerifier} will ignore the SSL validation for hostnames that are on the white-list.
 * 
 * @author Matthew Weiler
 */
@Component
public class SslBypassConfiguration
{

    /* PRIVATE VARIABLES */
    @Value("${application.ssl.bypass.enabled}") 
    private String sslVerificationBypassEnabled;
    @Autowired
    private WhitelistedConfig whitelistedConfig;

    /* PUBLIC METHODS */
    /**
     * This method will get the boolean flag to denote if the SSL handshake bypass is enabled.
     * 
     * @return
     * The boolean flag to denote if the SSL handshake bypass is enabled.
     */
    public boolean isSslVerificationBypassEnabled()
    {
        return StringUtils.isTrue(this.sslVerificationBypassEnabled, false);
    }

    /**
     * This method will get the {@link Map} of white-listed hostnames and their logical names as keys.
     * 
     * @return
     * The {@link Map} of white-listed hostnames and their logical names as keys.
     */
    public Map<String, String> getWhitelistedHostnames()
    {
        return this.whitelistedConfig.getHostnames();
    }

    /* PUBLIC CLASSES */
    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.ssl.bypass.whitelisted")
    public class WhitelistedConfig
    {

        /* PRIVATE VARIABLES */
        private Map<String, String> hostnames = new HashMap<String, String>();

        /* PUBLIC METHODS */
        /**
         * This method will get the {@link Map} of white-listed hostnames and their logical names as keys.
         * 
         * @return
         * The {@link Map} of white-listed hostnames and their logical names as keys.
         */
        public Map<String, String> getHostnames()
        {
            return this.hostnames;
        }

    }

}
```