# Issue with SSL certificate: "No peer certificate"

Tags: android, ssl, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm trying to authenticate through [Last.fm's API](http://www.last.fm/api/mobileauth).

On Android 4.3 it works just by doing

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/");
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

but on 2.3.3 I get

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

Then I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3904473/326849):

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

// Set verifier     
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);        

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/");
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

but I still get the same error.

Then I tried [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17159839/326849):

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParams, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpParams, true);

SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParams, schReg);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, httpParams);

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/");
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

and failed again.

Anybody can help?

Comment: USing a 2.3.3 emulator or device?

Comment: Device: Samsung Galaxy S1

Comment: A quick test. Can you open the url in Galaxy S browser - https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/ with the `https://` in front of it

Comment: Web page not available. The web page at `https://ws.audioscrobbler.com:445/2.0/` might be temporarily down...

Comment: oops. without the port number

Comment: That's what I get when typing `https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0` in the browser (I get the same when doing it in my laptop chrome browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some problem with the way the certificates are returned from the server OR may be android system keystore does not have the relevant root certs to validate and complete the handshake.

Looking at the [certificate chain information](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/) for the site mentioned in the question, it seems to me that the chain is not correctly sorted.

You can try the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115101/apache-httpclient-on-android-producing-certpathvalidatorexception-issuername/6631656#6631656)