# Android No peer certificate exception

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, httpclient

In my Android application I use **http** link for get  JSON response from server, now they changed to **https**. My code is return **No peer certificate** exception.

What the things need to get response from server using **https** in Android. This is the code I used for get response from server for **http**.

```
public static DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
public static ResponseHandler<String> resHandler;
public static List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
public static HttpPost httpPost;

     ....

httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.xxx.com/.../user/renting");
nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parking_spot_id".trim(),
        spotID));
    ....
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date[]", array[i]));
}

try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    jsonResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost, resHandler);
    Log.e("rent by day", jsonResponse);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code working well for using **http**.

1) What are the things I need to get for **https**.

2) What are the changes in the code.

Please help me.

Comment: Use this code: http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html

Comment: @Robert, I have confused in this concept. please tell me step by step approach to solve. please help me.

Comment: Read the section "Using your own trust store: HttpClient" it shows you the code you have to use. The problem is that the https server uses a certificate that is not trusted by your Android platform. Therefore you have to manually add it into your app.

Comment: I think this [answer][1] may help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531710/problems-with-https-no-peer-certificate-in-android?lq=1