# Android web-services using KSOAP2 and HTTPS

Tags: android, web-services, ssl, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to write a webservice for android using JAVA and KSOAP2. SOAP is the only  protocol I can use and ReST is not an option.

So, I successfully created the SOAP request and connected to the server using HTTP. But, I need HTTPS as sensitive information will be transferred. Disabling the certificate check is not an option as the data is sensitive and I MUST use SSL.

Since Android threw certification error in HTTPS, I created my own keystore following

1- http://blog.antoine.li/index.php/2010/10/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/

and added it to the project.

My code is similar to
2- http://www.techques.com/question/1-4646121/Not-trusted-certificate-using-ksoap2-android.

I have also gone through

3 - [Https Connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android#1000205)

4 - [Apache HttpClient on Android producing CertPathValidatorException (IssuerName != SubjectName)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115101/apache-httpclient-on-android-producing-certpathvalidatorexception-issuername)

but can't use them directly.

A pseudo code that shows the code in 1 in relation to the code in 2 with HTTPS will be greatly appreciated.

What does the last comment in 2 actually mean ? He uses HttpsTransportSE in his code but says he extended HttpsServiceConnectionSE. Can you show this in the pseudo code ?

Also, should I use HttpsTransportSE or HttpsServiceConnectionSE to provide the URL to which I will be connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me KSOAP + Web service WCF with eclipse.
Tomcat with certificat and login/password

May be this can help you

```
private static SoapObject getBody(final SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope) throws Exception {
        if (soapEnvelope.bodyIn == null) {
            throw new Exception("soapEnvelope.bodyIn=null");
        }
        else if (soapEnvelope.bodyIn.getClass() == SoapFault.class) {
            throw new ExceptionLogic((SoapFault) soapEnvelope.bodyIn));
        }
        else {
            return (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        }

    }

private static SoapSerializationEnvelope sendRequete(final SoapObject soapReq, final String classMappingName,
            final Class<?> classMapping, final int timeOutSpecial) {



        final SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;

        if (classMappingName != null) {
            soapEnvelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, classMappingName, classMapping);
        }

        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);

        try {

            final HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constante.urlWebService, timeOutSpecial);
            httpTransport.debug = BuildConfig.DEBUG;

            // Prod
            if (Constante.urlWebService.startsWith("https://")) {
                final List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
                headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
                        + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode((Constante.CERTIFICAT_LOGIN + ":" + Constante.CERTIFICAT_MDP).getBytes())));

                FakeX509TrustManager.allowAllSSL();
                httpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + "/" + soapReq.getName(), soapEnvelope, headerList);
            }
            // Test
            else {
                httpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + "/" + soapReq.getName(), soapEnvelope);
            }

            return soapEnvelope;
        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Erreur : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }



    private static class FakeX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
        private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;
        private final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[] {};

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return _AcceptedIssuers;
        }

        public static void allowAllSSL() {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                @Override
                public boolean verify(final String hostname, final SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            SSLContext context = null;
            if (trustManagers == null) {
                trustManagers = new TrustManager[] { new FakeX509TrustManager() };
            }
            try {
                context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
            }
            catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (final KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] arg0, final String arg1) throws CertificateException {

        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have client certificate and SSL call, Is this approach still working?

Comment: unfortunately, it's too long time. I don't know