# "SSLPeerUnverifiedException: no peer certificate" android backend

Tags: android, http-get

so this is for a project im doing for my school in which we need a backend.
our current setup is that the foreground is an android app, whereas the backend is a mySQL database that is located within my school's servers. The android app is supposed to interact with the mySQL database using a php script.

my php script is set currently hardcoded to return one single row from the mySQL database in JSON format.

my android code is as follows:

```
public static final String KEY = "URL of my PHP script";
InputStream is = null;
String result = "";
try{

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(KEY));
        Log.d(null,"there");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        Log.d(null, "here");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
```

However, I get an exception at the line

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

in which the error says: No Peer Certificate.

Anyone know what's wrong with it, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. This link worked for part of my needs.
http://www.knowledgebit.appspot.com/zahangirbd/TopicView.action;jsessionid=E2BZt_6bp4uFFbMyq42gWg?id=56001

however, there is still an issue with some links(i believe im not providing the proper certificate)

EDIT: so it turns out that the order of the certificates were the problem.

check this out, this helped me..
[Apache HttpClient on Android producing CertPathValidatorException (IssuerName != SubjectName)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115101/apache-httpclient-on-android-producing-certpathvalidatorexception-issuername)