# Android: cannot validate SSL certificate CertPath (corrupt certificate?)

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate

For my Android Application I'm using SSL to communicate with the server of a service providing an REST API.

Sometimes my calls throw an SSL Exception because the CertPathValidator cannot validate the certificate chain.

I get this message:

`java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: IssuerName(CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US) does not match SubjectName(CN=RapidSSL CA, O="GeoTrust, Inc.", C=US) of signing certificate`

Am I right, that this happens, because "GeoTrust Inc." does not match "GeoTrust, Inc." because the last one has a colon in the name and the first one does not contain it? Shouldn't I get always the same certificate by the server?

How can this validation exception be only thrown sometimes, but not always?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I still encouter it in 2012...

Comment: PS: There is a possible solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115101/apache-httpclient-on-android-producing-certpathvalidatorexception-issuername

Comment: @BurninLeo I'll just do not support plattforms below 2.3.3, I think. On 2.3.3 above it's working fine.