# Android 2.2 fails to load SSL certificate

Tags: android, ssl

I recently noticed that an application I'm building fails to load properly on Android 2.2 due to an SSL certificate warning:

[image]
[image]

But it works just fine on Android 2.3. I didn't try any other versions yet. Any ideas what might be going on?

My current hypothesis is that Android 2.2's browser do not load intermediate certificates, can anybody confirm or deny that?

Comment: There are some reports that connection may fail if certificates are sent by the server in the wrong order: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115101/apache-httpclient-on-android-producing-certpathvalidatorexception-issuername Mabye you are hitting the same issue

Comment: Did you figure out what it was at all?

Comment: I just found this link - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15968 could be helpful