# Android No peer certificate DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android, ssl, https

2 days I'm reading blog/answer/docs but no solution. I have a SimpleHosting on Gandi's servers with a SSL certificate https://auth.ruchers.net

As you can see, the certificate is valid.

But when I try to connect to this page with my DefaultHttpClient class I receive a [No peer certificate] error. My code is the same as you can find here : http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/

I read here [Android SSL No peer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130542/android-ssl-no-peer-certificate) and here [Android SSL - No Peer Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806128/android-ssl-no-peer-certificate) that the problem could be the order of the certificate chain... Ok, let's go, I'll control the chain :

```
openssl s_client -connect auth.ruchers.net:443
```

return

```
... no peer certificate available ...
```

To have a correct answer I need to specifie the servername

```
openssl s_client -connect auth.ruchers.net:443 -servername auth.ruchers.net
```

How can I say to my SSLSocketFactory to use "auth.ruchers.net" as servername for this certificate ?

Thank you for the help.

Best Regards,
Greg

Comment: i think u r requesting https o port 443 to defaultHttpClient

Comment: you need to have a library with SNI support. The one shipped with the SDK does not have SNI support. See http://blog.dev001.net/post/67082904181/android-using-sni-and-tlsv1-2-with-apache