# How do I know if a certificate authority is going to be trusted on a particular version of the Android SDK?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I can't find a list of authorities per Android SDK version anywhere. Most advice suggests running some code on a mounted device to determine the list of trusted root authorities for that device. This is simply not acceptable. If we're testing against a certain version, I need to know for that version, and each version above, what certificate authorities can we use? In particular, we need the CA to be trusted on Android 2.0+.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of trusted CA in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777058/list-of-trusted-ca-in-android)

Comment: I agree. It should be closed.

Comment: I don't really agree as the list of trusted root authorities is dependent of the android version. This is a different question.